# Visual Studio project doesn't compile when deleting a reference but the built EXE file runs without that same DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

1. I have created .NET 4.7.2 project and now refactoring and removing unused libraries.
2. By exe I mean successfully compiled exe file.

Comment: Are you sure the used libraries doesn't reference the "unused" libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Try To Delete Bin Folder From your Project Path

Comment: What exactly is the project and what is actualy used? For instance, is a library used at link time (and the .dll is never used after that). Some more details and examples would help to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple possibilities:

First: Compiled Exe didn't use the .dll at all as you said, so no piece of code will produce an exception because there's no call to that library inside it.

Second: Actually, the dll is somewhere in your computer (on an obscure folder, but registered) and the exe is accessing it witouth any problem

I would bet on first possibility